# Ошибка в составе придаточного определительного

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

**Вместо этого, подготовьте список напоминалок — список слов и коротких фраз, на который вы будете поглядывать и рассказывать своими словами то, что знаете.**

На слух предложение воспринимается нормально (по крайней мере, мне) и на первый взгляд не привлекает к себе внимания: вы будете поглядывать на подготовленный заранее список напоминалок и рассказывать своими словами то, что знаете (о тех вещах, которые указаны этими напоминалками).

Но если приглядеться, замечаем следующее. Придаточное прикреплено к главному при помощи союзного слова, которое в придаточном является дополнением в форме винительного падежа с предлогом "на", при этом вторая часть "и рассказывать своими словами то, что знаете" не связана с этим дополнением и напрямую не является определением для списка слов и коротких фраз. Чисто грамматически получается: "...список слов и коротких фраз, на который вы будете поглядывать и **на который вы будете** рассказывать своими словами то, что знаете", а это неправильно. Здесь ошибка? Или вторая часть придаточного также является определением, только более отдалённым по смыслу и грамматически не связанным с союзным словом, с помощью которого вводится определение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое построение предложения **некорректно,** но при редактировании лучше изменить грамматику, так как слово ***который*** и так имеет оттенок книжности, а при повторе все предложение выглядит громоздким и не сочетается с общим неформальным стилем фразы.

Вариант редактирования:

**Вместо этого подготовьте список "напоминалок" в виде  коротких фраз: на него вы будете поглядывать и рассказывать своими словами то, что знаете.**

Comment: Почему вы выбрали именно двоеточие, а не запятую и тире, например?

Comment: После «вместо этого» запятая обязательна: оборот не связан со сказуемым. _Никогда не рассказывайте по заготовленному тексту и тем более не читайте его с бумажки — ваша речь будет звучать заученно и нудно. Вместо этого, подготовьте…_

Comment: Здесь выбирается двоеточие или тире, т.к.к пауза увеличенная. Мне больше нравится двоеточие (с предупредительной интонацией), подчеркивающее пояснительный характер действия. "Вместо этого" в Нацкорусе редко обособляется, надо дополнительно посмотреть правило.

Answer (score 3):

Это предложение с **нарушением управления** союзным словом *который* в однородных придаточных. *Погладывать на что?*, но *рассказывать с помощью чего, с чем*?:

***Вместо этого подготовьте список напоминалок — список слов и коротких фраз, на который вы будете поглядывать и с помощью которого будете рассказывать своими словами то, что знаете.***